# Read "file.txt" content to List<String> dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get the text inside a ".txt" file, assign it to a variable and split it on "," in a list of String.

All works fine, the problem in that what is stored in the variable is "Instance of FutureString>".

So I added `.then((value) =>value);` in `_MyRead` to wait until the reading action is completed but the result is the same.

All works, I just need to get the text from the file. 
Actually a few minutes ago, the result of reading action was `null`, maybe this can help.

Code :

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
}

Future<File>  _localFile(String name) async {
final path = await _localPath;
print(path);
return File('$path/$name');
}

Future<String> _read(String filename) async {
try {
  final file = await _localFile(filename);

  // Read the file.
  return await file.readAsString();
} catch (e) {
  // If encountering an error, return 0.
  return "Can't read";
 }
}

String _MyRead(String filename){
 var read_ = _read(filename).then((value) =>value);
 String ridd= read_.toString();
 return ridd;
}

List<String> _getLanguages() {
  var _lan= _read("languages.txt");
  if ( _lan==null ) print("languages is empty");
  List<String> list =_lan.toString().split(",");
  return list;
}
```

Comment: `_read` is asynchronous, so it returns a `Future`. You need to `await` this future in order to get its result.

Comment: And I do this with ".then((value) =>value);".

Comment: I also tried to await in async function but the result of read is null

Comment: is the value of `path` printed to console correct?

Comment: @dev-aentgs Yes, the path is : /Users/mac.fede/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/39F2B320-D1DC-4105-A5FE-B71865F9D406/data/Containers/Data/Application/A57DEEBF-262B-4657-8C8D-450F824DADF4/Documents. I opened this path in the terminal and I found the right file inside , so it's good.

Comment: i suspect permission issues, could you try some other folder location ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs I can access the folder because I tried " print var read_" and it wrotes : "I love eat food ", that is the content of the file, so it can access. I think the problem is when I try to convert from "var" to "String".

Comment: Also ridd works, I printed it and it's the same content of "read_". All works but when in the build method I write "var bamboozle = _MyRead("languages.txt");" it says me "Instance of 'Future<String>".

Comment: @dev-aentgs Is like if I have to wait for the string, I feel the handling part isn't correct but Ican't wait in the build method.

Comment: I tried to wait with " var bamboozle = _MyRead(languages.txt).then((value) => String);" but nothing changes. The weird stuff is that I call the function only 1 time but checking the terminal output seems like if the function is called more than one time.

Comment: Terminal output : flutter: Instance of 'Future<Type>'I'm bamboozle
Reloaded 2 of 573 libraries in 374ms.
flutter: /Path to documents directory, it was too long...
flutter: Instance of 'Future<Type>'I'm bamboozle
flutter: /Users/mac.fede/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/39F2B320-D1DC-4105-A5FE-B71865F9D406/data/Containers/Data/Application/A57DEEBF-262B-4657-8C8D-450F824DADF4/Documents
flutter: Hello I love eat food! <3 I'm read_
flutter: Hello I love eat food! <3 I'm ridd
flutter: Hello I love eat food! <3 I'm read_
flutter: Hello I love eat food! <3 I'm ridd

Comment: "Hello I like eat food" should appear 2 times, actually it's 4/5, it's like if something is calling this function more than 1 time.

Comment: @MichealRoss what happens if you change `var read_ ` to `String read_` and return `read_` without the `ridd` variable ?

Comment: Nothing...read_ is correct because its content is "I love eat food" but when I call "_MyRead" in the build method with var bamboozle = _MyRead("languages.txt").then((value) => String); It prints me :"Instance of 'Future<Type>'".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Future<String>_MyRead(String filename) async {
 var read_ = await _read(filename);
 String ridd= read_.toString();
 return ridd;
}
```

and you need to await when you call the read function since it returns a Future:

```
var _lan= await _read("languages.txt");
```

(Don't forget to make your function asynchronous then)

Comment: I tried your code, inside ridd there is "Instance of 'Future<String>". Maybe the problem is inside the read to get the file but I used the code provided by devs on official documentation of Flutter. I'll post it.